# What constitutes a bash?

Tags: card-hunter

The basic "Bash" attack card has the ability of "Add 2 damage to any other Bash you play.  Keep.".

The "Bruiser" Martial Skill has the same ability.

What cards qualify as a "Bash"?  Is it only cards that have the exact name of "Bash", or is it any card that has "bash" in the name, or any melee attack that slides the opponent back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Bash" cards are indeed those that have the "Bash" word in their name, e.g. Strong Bash, Bash and so on.

Don't get it confused with the "Crushing" keyword you see in the middle of the card. Not all crushing cards are bashes - there are also bludgeons and maybe some other.